# Употребление частицы не

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать слово  в  предложении: "... в случае *не прохождения* задания, эксперт не будет аттестован". Не прохождения слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

Здесь - слитно. "Непрохождение" - самостоятельное слово.
Хотя от всей вашей фразы за версту несёт махровым канцеляритом. Нельзя ли как-нибудь более по-людски то же самое сказать? "Эксперт не будут аттестован, если он не выполнит задание".
Почему задание обязательно надо проходить?

Answer (score 0):

"Эксперт не пройдет аттестацию,если не выполнит задание" тож неплохо